# Flash in Facebook feed for other things than games or ads : is it allowed?

Tags: facebook, flash, feed

I would like to make a small quizz widget (with an internal scrollbar) in flash so it can be directly used within the facebook feed by the persons who see the post.

I saw that a game can directly be played in the Facebook feed according to this facebook article :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/feed-gaming/

My question is : 
**Does Facebook allow other things than games or ads to be played/used directly in the news feed.**

Does someone have an example of a flash widget that was allowed by Facebook that is not a game or an ad?

I also saw this article explaining that Facebook will stop supporting Adobe Flash in desktop News Feed ad campaigns : 
http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/08/06/facebook-to-stop-supporting-adobe-flash-in-desktop-news-feed-ad-campaigns/
Does this means that feed gaming is going to disappear?